# How can I copy from and scale multiple images at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, image-editing

Context: I am creating materials for a 3D renderer that contain multiple textures for colour, roughness, normals, etc. I have an image of some grass blades that looks like this:
[image: base colour of the grass blades]

Alongside appropriate normal and roughness maps. What I would like to do is cut out individual blades of grass and arrange them into tufts of grass in a separate image. The problem is that in order to make the other textures line up, I would need to replicate the exact, pixel perfect steps manually on every map.

Is there a way to copy from and manipulate all of these maps at once?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to make a normal and roughness map for each blade of grass and then separate each image, normal map, and roughness map? You ask how to copy and manipulate all of the maps at once, but how are you trying to manipulate the maps?

Comment: @AndrewH I have the normal and roughness maps for the image above. I want to be able to select individual blades of grass in the image and be able to copy paste the selection, and then translate, rotate and scale the selection to move each blade of grass into the correct orientation. But I would like the normal and roughness maps to follow along (perhaps as seperate layers). The end result will be an image of a tuft of grass, with seperate images for the normal and roughness maps for this tuft of grass.

Comment: it sounds like maybe saving each blade as a separate file, and importing as a smart object might be what you are trying to do, but it's not very clear what you are asking.  The image you posted, is it a scan? Flattened? or are all the blades of grass already separate pieces and layers in a PSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Place your image texture, normal map, and roughness map  in one document in Photoshop
2. Turn off visibility of the normal and roughness map layers. Then use the Magic Wand Tool (W) and select the green background on the texture layer.
3. Invert the selection and apply a vector layer mask
4. I created a new layer and with the new layer selected, went to "Image -> Apply Image.."
5. Select the isolated texture grass, inverse the selection and delete the background of the normal and roughness map.
6. You can then make a selection of each blade (texture, normal and roughness) and make a new layer. You would need to make a selection for each layer and hit CTRL + J or CMD + J.
7. Group the isolated blade texture, normal and roughness map by selecting the layers and hitting CTRL + G or CMD + G

[image: isolating textures]

So if you want to scale or rotate 1 blade of grass with the maps changing, then you make the adjustments to the group layer.